# Python sum of big float numbers

Tags: python, floating-point

i am trying to add some float values in python 3 (never tested in 2) and i get some odd results, the only varying factor being the order of the elements in the summation.

```
a = [-1e30, 1e30, 1, 3]
print(sum(a))   # return 4.0

a = [-1e30, 1, 3, 1e30]
print(sum(a))   # return 0.0
```

Can anyone please tell me what did i miss here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're doing sums of sequences of floating point numbers, you want to use `math.fsum`:

```
>>> a = [-1e30, 1e30, 1, 3]
>>> math.fsum(a)
4.0
>>> a = [-1e30, 1, 3, 1e30]
>>> math.fsum(a)
4.0
```

Using the `sum` builtin is not going to get you good answers for very large (or small) floating point numbers because of the inherent precision problems.  You can get a pretty good view of the gory details at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the book reference. I will take a look at it.
It is interesting though that if i put the big numbers one after the other i get a 4 though, and that's what i couldn't explain.

Comment: @TheBestPessimist: If you put them one after another they get to apply to each other first, and effectively equal zero.  However, adding anything to either one of those numbers is not going to increase their value, so separating them just means the numbers in the middle get lost.

Comment: yes i reached the same conclusion. I was thinking that if i add a big enough number, it would actually make a difference. Am i right?

Comment: @TheBestPessimist: Yes, although at those values, the number would have to be *very* big.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Floating point numbers have a 53-bit coefficient ("the number before the `e`").

`10**30` is *way* bigger than `2**53`, so adding 4 to that number is lost in the limits of precision for floating point numbers.

```
>>> 2**53
9007199254740992
>>> 10**30
1000000000000000000000000000000
>>> float(2**53)
9007199254740992.0
>>> float(2**53) + 1
9007199254740992.0
```

Comment: This `float(2**53) < (float(2**53) + 1) = False`  helped me a bit understand how it goes, but some things are still unclear.

Comment: The “coefficient” is properly called the “significand”, and improperly but extremely commonly called “mantissa”. And the fact that 10**30 is larger than 2**53 is not directly related to the fact that adding 4 to it is imprecise. 0.2 and 0.1 are small but adding them is imprecise. 2**60 and 2**60 are large but adding them is precise.